# MySql - How to sort vertically stored data to order by one of field's values horizontally?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 mysql tables named records, fields and fields_values.

**Records table** consists of meta data about records and record id.

**Fields table**
No. of fields for a record are variable, and can be added dynamically.
Fields values contain info about fields shown on the record form eg: what type of fields is it, whether it is required or no etc.

**Fields values table**
This table contains actual data of records for each field.

For example, these tables have data as below:

```
Records Table:
+----+-------------+------------+--------+
| id | category_id | created_by | status |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+
|  1 |           1 |         10 |      1 |
|  2 |           1 |         10 |      1 |
|  3 |           1 |         10 |      1 |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+
```

```
Fields Table:
+----+------------+------------+------+--------+----------+------------+
| id |   title    |   alias    | type | status | required | created_by |
+----+------------+------------+------+--------+----------+------------+
|  1 | First Name | first_name | text |      1 |        1 |        100 |
|  2 | Last Name  | last_name  | text |      1 |        1 |        100 |
|  3 | City       | city       | text |      1 |        1 |        100 |
|  4 | State      | state      | text |      1 |        1 |        100 |
|  5 | Country    | country    | text |      1 |        1 |        100 |
|  6 | Mobile     | mobile     | text |      1 |        1 |        100 |
+----+------------+------------+------+--------+----------+------------+
```

```
Fields Values Table:
+----+----------+-----------+------------+
| id | field_id | record_id |   value    |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |        1 |         1 | Andy       |
|  2 |        2 |         1 | A          |
|  3 |        3 |         1 | Manchester |
|  4 |        4 |         1 | NWE        |
|  5 |        5 |         1 | UK         |
|  6 |        6 |         1 | 1234567898 |
|  7 |        1 |         2 | Sandy      |
|  8 |        2 |         2 | B          |
|  9 |        3 |         2 | NYC        |
| 10 |        4 |         2 | NY         |
| 11 |        5 |         2 | USA        |
| 12 |        6 |         2 | 1234567891 |
| 13 |        1 |         3 | Mandy      |
| 14 |        2 |         3 | P          |
| 15 |        3 |         3 | Mumbai     |
| 16 |        4 |         3 | MH         |
| 17 |        5 |         3 | IN         |
| 18 |        6 |         3 | 1234567893 |
+----+----------+-----------+------------+
```

And, I want to records as below and want to sort it based on one of the fields as selected by user eg: country

```
+----+------------+-----------+------------+-------+-----------+------------+
| id | first_name | last_name |    city    | state | country ^ |   mobile   |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------+------------+
|  3 | Mandy      | P         | Mumbai     | MH    | IN        | 1234567893 |
|  1 | Andy       | A         | Manchester | NWE   | UK        | 1234567898 |
|  2 | Sandy      | B         | NYC        | NY    | USA       | 1234567891 |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+-------+-----------+------------+
```

How do I **sort such vertically stored data to order by one of field's values in a single query** so that it can be shown horizontally?

Comment: Question is about how to sort such data, it is not about presentation.

Comment: This is called a pivot, see e.g. [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12004603). To order, you can e.g. just add `order by 6` (which orders by the 6th column) or `order by country` (if you know its name/alias).

Comment: I see no query here

Comment: Also, you have multiple identical field_id/record_id tuples. Can this be correct?

Comment: Fixed incorrect dummy data @Strawberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to observe that it would be more usual to write that this way...

```
SELECT r.id
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 1 THEN value END) first_name 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 2 THEN value END) last_name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 3 THEN value END) city
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 4 THEN value END) state 
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 5 THEN value END) country
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_id = 6 THEN value END) mobile
  FROM records r
  LEFT 
  JOIN fields_values v
    ON v.record_id = r.id
 GROUP
    BY r.id;
```

Comment: Not according to your schema